# pandas dataframe converts datatype of the input json even when dtype is object

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a string which has json data into pandas dataframe.

```
{"timestamp": "Wed Dec 04 11:30:04 GMT+05:30 2019","lat": 12.739265, "lon": 77.788135, "odometer": 20, "speed": 35.0, "id": "143455434", "error_code": 0}
{"timestamp": "Wed Dec 04 11:30:13 GMT+05:30 2019","lat": 73.739265, "lon": 71.788135, "odometer": 40, "speed": 25.5, "id": "null"}
```

This is what I use

```
pd.read_json(string, lines=True, dtype=object)
```

If you look at the datatypes of this dataframe all will be object

```
timestamp     object
lat           object
lon           object
odometer      object
speed         object
id            object
error_code    object
dtype: object
```

But it converts the timestamp to datetime when you get to the individual element.

```
timestamp   lat lon odometer    speed   id  error_code
0   2019-12-04 11:30:04-05:30   12.739265   77.788135   20  35.0    143455434   0.0
1   2019-12-04 11:30:13-05:30   73.739265   71.788135   40  25.5    null    nan
```

HAve a look, it has converted the timestamp to datetime which I do not want. I would like it to read it as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `convert_dates=False` or `keep_default_dates=False` parameter in [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html):

```
df = pd.read_json(string,lines=True, dtype=object, convert_dates=False)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_json(string, lines=True, dtype=object, keep_default_dates=False)
```

---

```
print (df)
                            timestamp      lat      lon odometer speed  \
0  Wed Dec 04 11:30:04 GMT+05:30 2019  12.7393  77.7881       20    35   
1  Wed Dec 04 11:30:13 GMT+05:30 2019  73.7393  71.7881       40  25.5   

          id error_code  
0  143455434          0  
1       null        NaN
```

Comment: That was quick... let me check

Comment: Yes the timestamp worked but if you look at error_code it is also getting converted to float 0.0

Comment: How to convert everything as string in dataframe? when you use dtypes, it shows all objects

Comment: @Nipun - Use `dtype=str` but still `0.0`, it seems bug :(

Comment: Oh... yes causing my conversion to integer failing. As a workaround, I am converting it to float first and then to int